# Jquery Organic Tabs - Detect Current Tab

Tags: jquery

I'm using https://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/

which is working great but I need to place the tabs both above and below the content. Copy/Paste the list works but it does not recognize the "current" classname. For example, click the the top nav, the bottom nav does not get highlighted.

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="nav-one"><a href="#description" class="current">description</a></li>
<li class="nav-two"><a href="#itinerary">itinerary</a></li>
<li class="nav-three"><a href="#included">included</a></li>
<li class="nav-four"><a href="#faqs">fAQ'S</a></li>
</ul>
```

and Calling the plugin

```
$("#tourtabs").organicTabs();
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to find the current selected element is simply selecting it directly using JQuery, since it seems that the "Organic Tabs" does not store the current tab value anywhere.

Eg:

```
$("#tourtabs .current")[0]
```